# what does this C code do with return code?

Tags: c, error-handling, return-value

A function returns *TRUE* on failure and *FALSE* on success.

I see some such functions do this towards end of itself:

```
return return_code != 0;
```

or

```
return (return_code != 0);
```

And in this function, at each error case, it returns *TRUE* - which is fine and what it should do in case of error.

But what does above code signify? Is it trying to make sure that return_code is FALSE - explicitly?

Comment: It's indicating success or failure by returning 0 or 1. It's not obvious from this code which means what, but it's probably because return_code may contain more information than just success/failure. Doing !!return_code will do the same, which I think looks better. The same works for pointers, where !!pointer returns 1 or 0, if the pointer is not or is NULL, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both depend on the value of return_code:

```
return_code = 0;

return(return_code != 0); // returns false
return(return_code == 0); // returns true
```

and

```
return_code = "anything but a zero";

return(return_code != 0); // returns true
return(return_code == 0); // returns false
```

Comment: wow, so it does assignment? thats kind of not not right? return_code should be decided based on events that occur in function and not explicitly like this....

Comment: At some point in the function, return_code would have to be defined and a value assigned to it. it's not a 'default' variable in C.

Comment: aaah.... I got it now. If a function is designed to return FALSE on success and TRUE on failure, on every failing condition, you return TRUE and get out. But if you reach `return(return_code != 0);` that means, everything is good and return_code is zero. So it will return FALSE - what we actually want for failure. - But all this seems unnecessary to me. Somehow I am missing the point here.

Comment: Consider the calling context. the function may be named "didItWork()", which implies that returning a false value means it failed. But internally in the function, return_code is set to true for whatever reason, so you have to invert the value to make it a "false" to make the function name make sense.

Answer (score 6):

I would say is trying to collapse from all the possible integer values to just those of `0` and `1`. I'm assuming that the function returns an integral type; evaluating the result as a boolean expression forces the result to just those two values.

Answer (score 1):

Just a further explanaion -

It is most likely that somewhere in the program TRUE and FALSE are defined:

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0
```

When a boolean expression is evaluated, the result is always 1 or 0, 1 if the boolean expression evaluates to true, and 0 if it is false. That is why you can test if a boolean expression evaluates to TRUE or FALSE. If you're just curious about boolean expressions and want more basic information, here is a decent [tutorial](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx3c.html).

Answer (score 1):

A simple example to make it clear, with a function that divides a with b. Returns true if the division can be evaluated false otherwise

```
bool div(double a, double b, double& r)
{
   int return_code = 1;
   if (b == 0) // cannot divide
      return_code = 0;
   else
      r = a/b;

   return (return_code != 0);
}
```

In this simple example only if b==0 the return_code will be 0 so as Marc replied it will return false. In any other case it will return true. Of course there is no reason to do  something like this in such a simple function. In more complicated function where the success or not can change in many places, it is a common practice to use such return statements.